# Update a score from player with mysql

Tags: php, iphone, mysql

I have a simple online highscore system for my iphone game, with a mysql database, which has a field rank, name, score and udid (unique device identifier). I don't want to have multiple scores from a udid, and my question is : how can I make sure that the old score is removed and the new one is inserted, with the new highscore.

My code for inserting the score is :

```
// Insert the score

$retval = mysql_query("INSERT INTO $table(
        udid,
        name,
        score

    ) VALUES (
        '$udid',
        '$name',
        '$score'

    )",$conn);

if($retval) {
    echo "Inserted score $score for $name";
   }
```

So I want to overwrite the old score and insert the new one.

Thanks for your help,

Cheers, Joe

EDIT :

I am not a php programmer, so if you want, please provide a simple example, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) works fine, as others have suggested, however, REPLACE does an actual delete of the row and then inserts the new one, which is expensive performance-wise.

I recommend that you use [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) instead:

```
INSERT INTO tablename (udid, name, score)
  VALUES (12, 'Marcus', 100)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE score = 100 WHERE udid = 12
```

Ensure that there is a primary or unique key on `udid` for this to work.

Comment: $retval = mysql_query("INSERT INTO $table(
   udid,
   name,
   score
                        
  ) VALUES (
   '$udid',
   '$name',
   '$score'
                   
  ) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE score WHERE udid = $udid", $conn); <BR> but it gives Unable to insert score You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE udid = 1111' at line 11

Comment: Almost. You must have an assignment like this `UPDATE score = '$score' WHERE`.

Comment: $retval = mysql_query("INSERT INTO $table(
   udid,
   name,
   score
                        
  ) VALUES (
   '$udid',
   '$name',
   '$score'
  ) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE score = '$score' WHERE udid = '$udid'
", $conn); Gives : right syntax to use near 'WHERE '1111'' at line 11

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `REPLACE` keyword in mysql: [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html).

> REPLACE works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in the
>   table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE
>   index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted.

Answer (score 1):

i think what you want is to update when it exists or otherwise insert. There is a way to do that built in called [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) that has worked for me in the same situation in the past.

Comment: This is probably the best approach - but make sure that "udid" is marked as a primary or unique key in your MySQL table, or this won't work

Answer (score 0):

What you want is `REPLACE INTO`.

Read more [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html).

Comment: I am a iphone programmer and don't know excactly how to implement this, can you provide an example? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Syntax is on the page I linked, but essentially it allows you to either INPUT a new record or UPDATE an existing record based on a unique field (in your case, `udid`).

Example:
`REPLACE INTO your_table (udid, name, score) VALUES ('$udid', '$name', '$score')`

(Assumes you have properly escaped your variables)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use an update-statement to overwrite a value in the database.

```
update table set field=value where id=$theudid
```